# How should I add progressbar to actionbar in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-actionbar

I want to add `progressbar` to `actionbar` but I don't know how to do it

**This is my menu items**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/btnUpdateInActionBarMain"
      android:title="Barcode"
      android:icon="@drawable/icoUpdate1"
      android:showAsAction="always">
  </item>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/icoSearch"
    android:showAsAction="always">
  </item>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/btnBarcode"
    android:title="Barcode"
    android:icon="@drawable/icoBarcode"
    android:showAsAction="always">
  </item>

</menu>
```

**This my `OnCreateOptionsMenu()`**

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.action_bar, menu);
    ActionBarMenu = menu;

    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I want to show a `progressbar` instead of btnUpdateInActionBarMain, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of trying to solve this problem i solved it, maybe it's not pretty but it is working fine for me
so this is my actionBar_progressBar.axml file in menu folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp">
    </ProgressBar>
```

This is my action_bar.xml file in menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item
          android:id="@+id/btnUpdateHolder"
          android:title="Barcode"
          android:icon="@drawable/icoUpdate1"
          android:showAsAction="always">
      </item>
      <item
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/icoSearch"
        android:showAsAction="always">
      </item>
      <item
        android:id="@+id/btnBarcode"
        android:title="Barcode"
        android:icon="@drawable/icoBarcode"
        android:showAsAction="always">
      </item>
    </menu>
```

This is my actionBar_Update.axml file in menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdateInActionBarMain"
            android:background="@drawable/icoUpdate1" />
```

so i changed OnCreateOptionsMenu()  like this:

```
private IMenu ActionBarMenu;
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.action_bar, menu);
            ActionBarMenu = menu;
            menuItem = ActionBarMenu.FindItem(Resource.Id.btnUpdateHolder);
            menuItem.SetActionView(Resource.Menu.actionBar_progressBar);
            menuItem.ExpandActionView();
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

After doing my job to bring the icon back to normal i do this

```
menuItem.SetActionView(Resource.Menu.actionBar_Update);
btnUpdate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnUpdateInActionBarMain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add as in your menu

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/yourIcon"
        clasificados:showAsAction="always"
        clasificados:actionViewClass="android.widget.ProgressBar"/>
```

Comment: I have this error "namespace prefix clasificados is not defined"

Comment: add this in menu tag  -> 
xmlns:clasificados="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: then let me know